# Criando strings com caracteres especiais

Tags: c, string

Eu estou fazendo um programa simulador de relógio. Porém, ao imprimir o resultado, estou tendo erros.

Segue exemplo de como faço:

```
float abc = 1:00 + 2:00 ; 

printf("horario: %f",abc);
```

Como faço então para fazer e imprimir uma string com caracteres especiais?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vejamos...

Existem vários tipos de abstração de dados. Em **C**, por exemplo, temos dois tipos que se encaixam na dúvida: `float` e `char` (em cadeia ou *array*).

O tipo `float` armazena números em ponto flutuante. Trocando em miúdos, *números com casas decimais* (alguma coisa *vírgula* outra coisa). Portanto, ele não armazena caracteres diferentes de algarismos - e, *de certa forma*, o "ponto" que acaba por indicar as casas decimais (*aqui usamos a vírgula mas, ao programar, adotamos o padrão inglês*).

O tipo `char` armazena 1 caractere qualquer dados os limites de ambos compilador e sistema operacional. Todavia, pode criar uma cadeia (array) de `char` que simula o conceito de *string*.

Vale lembrar que os tipos não conseguem fazer as operações um do outro usando os mesmos símbolos. Ou seja: você consegue "somar" dois caracteres numéricos mas isso não significa adicionar dois números. Significa *concatenar* (ou juntar). Exemplos:

- `'a' + 'b'` resulta em `"ab"`
- `'1' + '1'` não resulta em `2` e sim em `"11"`.

### Problema

Considerando seu código

```
float abc = 1:00 + 2:00 ; 

printf("horario: %f",abc);
```

Você está justamente tentando somar algo que não faz parte do que o tipo float entende: os dois pontos **`:`**. Você deve primeiro somar as horas e só então transformar em *string* da forma apropriada - considerando C, C++ e Rust.

### Solução:

Por exemplo, em C, poderia-se considerar:

```
int hora_1 = 1;
int hora_2 = 20;

int soma_hora = hora_1 + hora_2;

printf("Horário: %d:00", %soma_hora);
```

Neste exemplo, fiz a soma das horas. Note que os dois pontos ficou a cargo do `printf` já que não há necessidade de lidar com ele para cálculos de horas.

Foi utilizado `int` pois o `float` é desnecessário neste exemplo - e talvez seja mais interessante dividir os minutos e as horas para tornar o trabalho menos complexo. Não foi levando em conta os minutos pois é interessante que pense em como ligar com casos em que a soma fique, por exemplo, igual a 61 - mesmo que não seja necessário, é interessante do ponto de vista técnico para quem está aprendendo.

Seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
float abc = 1 + 2 ; 

printf("horario: %f:00", abc);
```

### Notas finais

Se realmente for tratar as horas com "dois pontos" - ou seja, com *strings* - vou sugerir que leia sobre as funções que lidam com isso na linguagem de sua preferência. Em C/C++, pode olhar [neste site](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/apend/string.h.html) para possíveis utilitários. E a teoria fica [aqui](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/string.html) e [aqui](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/string-manip.html). E claro, vale a pena sempre procurar no Google outras formas que possam surtir mais efeito em seu entendimento.

Comment: vlw amigo ^^" resolvido

Comment: @GustavoAlves sem problemas! Se a resposta foi adequada e solucionou, pode marcar ela com o sinal de "certo" bem rente ao topo da resposta para que ela não fique em aberto.